# django redirect going to other url

Tags: django, url, redirect, view

When i redirect after my register, or login with a user, it goes back to the loginscreen instead of the next template. Can someone please tell me where i go wrong?

My urls

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register_user, name='register_user'),
)
```

My register_user view:

```
def register_user(request):
    # False till someone fills in and sends
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()

    return render_to_response('register.html', {'form': form},         
                                context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Now when i register i get redirected back to 'login', instead of 'index'

Comment: Is the `index` view decorated with `login_required` ?

Comment: at the moment my index ist still jsut a test    def index(request):
 return render(request, 'index.html')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the same url for `login` and `index`.

```
url(r'^$', views.login, name='login'),
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
```

The should differ from each other:

```
url(r'^login/$', views.login, name='login'),
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
```

Comment: Hello, thought it was also possible to have multiple views on 1 url as long as you ask for the right view?  (enough sites only having 1 url that runs the whole site?)  but lets fix it this way for now

Comment: @HansdeJong https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse reverse() function only creates a url string, and then your code just grabs the firt appropriate url in your urls.py, which was login in that case

Comment: Okay that explains more indeed. Any idea how i can solve it on the same url. Should i use a render(request) ?